# Find center point of two tris - ThreeJS

Tags: three.js

I am currently trying to figure out how I would go about finding the center point of two tris. I am spawning a cube currently at the centroid of a face. I have access to both faces, but I am unsure of what I should do to calculate the center point vector 3 to pass the cube for its position.

```
calculateFacePositions(index){
  var geo = this.cylinder.geometry;
  var face = this.cylinder.geometry.faces[index];

  var vertices = geo.vertices;
  var v1 = vertices[face.a];
  var v2 = vertices[face.b];
  var v3 = vertices[face.c];

  var centroid = new THREE.Vector3();
  centroid.x = ( v1.x + v2.x + v3.x ) / 3;
  centroid.y = ( v1.y + v2.y + v3.y ) / 3;
  centroid.z = ( v1.z + v2.z + v3.z ) / 3;
  
  console.log("centroid x: " + centroid.x);
  console.log("centroid y: " + centroid.y);
  console.log("centroid z: " + centroid.z);

  return centroid;

}
```

EDIT: I solved this by adding both centroids that make up a face together and dividing by 2! Now I am just looking to make sure the cube I spawn is the same facing as the face I place it on.

Here is what worked for me:

```
calculateFacePositions(index){
  var geo = this.cylinder.geometry;

  var faceA = this.cylinder.geometry.faces[index];

  var verticesA = geo.vertices;
  var v1A = verticesA[faceA.a];
  var v2A = verticesA[faceA.b];
  var v3A = verticesA[faceA.c];

  var centroidA = new THREE.Vector3();
  centroidA.x = ( v1A.x + v2A.x + v3A.x ) / 3;
  centroidA.y = ( v1A.y + v2A.y + v3A.y ) / 3;
  centroidA.z = ( v1A.z + v2A.z + v3A.z ) / 3;
  
  var faceB = this.cylinder.geometry.faces[index+1];

  var verticesB = geo.vertices;
  var v1B = verticesB[faceB.a];
  var v2B = verticesB[faceB.b];
  var v3B = verticesB[faceB.c];

  var centroidB = new THREE.Vector3();
  centroidB.x = ( v1B.x + v2B.x + v3B.x ) / 3;
  centroidB.y = ( v1B.y + v2B.y + v3B.y ) / 3;
  centroidB.z = ( v1B.z + v2B.z + v3B.z ) / 3;

  var combineCentroids = new THREE.Vector3();
  combineCentroids.x = (centroidA.x + centroidB.x) / 2;
  combineCentroids.y = (centroidA.y + centroidB.y) / 2;
  combineCentroids.z = (centroidA.z + centroidA.z) / 2;
 
  return combineCentroids;

}
```

I would also like the spawned cube to have the same facing as the face where it is being spawned.

EDIT #2:
I solved my latest issue of varying axis placement on the center points. It was due to how I was averaging my vector 3's apparently ThreeJS is very particular about adding vectors and I was unaware of a built in addvectors method! So from my previous code block, I replaced the combineCentroids v3 with the following and now have perfectly center placed cubes!

```
calculateFacePositions(index){
  var geo = this.cylinder.geometry;

  var faceA = this.cylinder.geometry.faces[index];

  var verticesA = geo.vertices;
  var v1A = verticesA[faceA.a];
  var v2A = verticesA[faceA.b];
  var v3A = verticesA[faceA.c];

  var centroidA = new THREE.Vector3();
  centroidA.x = ( v1A.x + v2A.x + v3A.x ) / 3;
  centroidA.y = ( v1A.y + v2A.y + v3A.y ) / 3;
  centroidA.z = ( v1A.z + v2A.z + v3A.z ) / 3;
  
  var faceB = this.cylinder.geometry.faces[index+1];

  var verticesB = geo.vertices;
  var v1B = verticesB[faceB.a];
  var v2B = verticesB[faceB.b];
  var v3B = verticesB[faceB.c];

  var centroidB = new THREE.Vector3();
  centroidB.x = ( v1B.x + v2B.x + v3B.x ) / 3;
  centroidB.y = ( v1B.y + v2B.y + v3B.y ) / 3;
  centroidB.z = ( v1B.z + v2B.z + v3B.z ) / 3;

  var centroidAverage = new THREE.Vector3();
  centroidAverage.addVectors(centroidA, centroidB);
  centroidAverage.x = centroidAverage.x / 2;
  centroidAverage.y = centroidAverage.y / 2;
  centroidAverage.z = centroidAverage.z / 2;

  return centroidAverage;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `Face` object has a [`.normal` property](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/core/Face3.normal), which indicates the direction the face is pointing. You could extract this vector, and use the cube's `.lookAt()` method to face the same direction as the face normal:

```
let direction = faceA.normal;
let position = calculateFacePositions(index);

box.lookAt(direction);
box.position.copy(position);
```

Make sure you apply rotation before setting position, since normals are vectors no larger than 1 unit in magnitude, the box should be at (0, 0, 0) for the `.lookAt()` calculation to work.

If the cube is in the middle of two `Face`s, you could take both their normals and average them.

Comment: Thank you! Yea I stumbled into the normals last night on the faces and was successfully getting the desired rotation. But I found another issue where with my averaging logic, it seems they vary on the axis on the face that they are placed on. So if I remove the averaging logic they are all at the same height on the faces but if I add the averaging in to center them they seem to place randomly on the Y axis on the planes. I just also added logic to average the normals but that seems to work with the same as before where I was just taking one of the faces normals for rotation. Which makes sense.